# I just cant find a fitting solution for this MySQL "Exists()" error

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, parsing, parse-error

I already searched stackoverflow for like an hour, but no solution can solve my problem.

I want to run this code:

```
for (var skin in body){
  connection.query(`IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT MarketName FROM Skins WHERE MarketName = ?);
            THEN
                INSERT INTO Skins (MarketName) VALUES (?);
            END IF;`,[skin, skin]); }
```

But if I run this with nodejs, I get this error:

> /var/www/html/bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:80
>               throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
>               ^
>        Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
>       check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT MarketName FROM
>   Skins WHERE MarketName = 'Nova | Moon in Li' at line 1
>               at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/var/www/html/bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:52:14)
>               at Query.ErrorPacket (/var/www/html/bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:77:18)
>               at Protocol._parsePacket (/var/www/html/bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:279:23)
>               at Parser.write (/var/www/html/bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:12)
>               at Protocol.write (/var/www/html/bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
>               at Socket. (/var/www/html/bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:103:28)
>               at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
>               at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
>               at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:266:12)
>               at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:253:11)
>               --------------------
>               at Protocol._enqueue (/var/www/html/bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:145:48)
>               at Connection.query (/var/www/html/bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:208:25)
>               at Request._callback (/var/www/html/bot/index.js:531:16)
>               at Request.self.callback (/var/www/html/bot/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
>               at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
>               at Request.emit (events.js:213:7)
>               at Request. (/var/www/html/bot/node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
>               at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
>               at Request.emit (events.js:210:7)
>               at IncomingMessage. (/var/www/html/bot/node_modules/request/request.js:1085:12)

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL only allows `IF` statements in programming blocks -- stored procedures, triggers, and the like.

The correct way to do what you want is to create a unique index or constraint on `Skins(MarketName)`.  That way, the *database* ensures integrity of the data.  You can do this as:

```
create unique index unq_skins_marketname on Skins(MarketName);
```

Then, an attempt to insert a duplicate will result in an error.  You can generally avoid this by doing:

```
insert into skins(marketname)
    values (?)
    on duplicate key marketname = values(marketname);  -- this is a no-op
```

Comment: First of all: Thanks for answering my Question and giving me such a great advice.

Comment: But I just tried it out and I think I am to "nooby" to implement this. Can you help me a bit more? I hate leeching, but I need your help.. :/ This is a link to the complete code: [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/yNWUxp8F) If you cant help me or dont want to help me further this is okey, you already helped me a lot ^^